# How can i get info from object with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this model in my view :

```
{dpt:[{pos:05, name:Hautes-Alpes}, {pos:10, name:Aube}, {pos:51, name:Marne}]}
```

I want to get '05', '10' & '51' in my controller. How can i do for that ?

Thanks rgds

Comment: Whats the variable name that's located in? Just do `data.dpt[0].pos`

Comment: hate to say this but if your knowledge of objects and arrays is that limited...angular my not be for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's an array, just don't forget to specify the index:

```
data.dpt[0].pos
```

Or you can loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.dpt.length; i++)
```